# Compressing AES

Tags: aes, compression

I have this program which encrypts multiple files using AES then compress it using LZO into one single file. The problem is that the final file is almost equal in size than all the files which means LZO is not doing his job properly. Also, if I only encrypt files, the size is almost the same.
I've also tried to compress data and then encrypt it, but the result is the same.
AES can't be compressed at all or it can't be compressed by LZO?
What do you recommend to use in compression for maximum compatibility with AES? I want both speed and good compressio ratio. Like, over 100mb/s speed and ~2.0 compression ratio. Thanks.

Comment: Compress before encrypting, not after. The only way to encrypt a ciphertext *at all* is by breaking the encryption. (But that might cause some security issues, the CRIME attack against TLS was due to compression.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've tried that already, and the result is the same. I edited the question. Sorry for the lack of informations.

Comment: @Shockwave: if your _"I've tried that already"_ refers to _"Compress before encrypting, not after"_, then you need to better understand the nature of the content of your _"multiple files"_ and find or devise a compression algorithm suitable for that. If your _"multiple files"_ are already compressed (including many common sound, image, video formats), that will be very hard.

Comment: @fgrieu 99% of the files are text files, 1% are TGA images. They are not encrypted before by me. They are as they were made by the graphic editor. Sure, I would like to compress also a lot of TGA files, but for now that's what I've tested on...

Comment: @Shockwave: you wrote _" I've tried that already, and the result is the same"_. I find it unlikely that lzo (with default parameters) fails to compress text files, even more the concatenation of text files. I guess that you did not correctly _"Compress before encrypting, not after"_.

Comment: @fgrieu I was testing what you just said while I was waiting for the responses. I am using some kind of _open_-source code which is using a special object to work with data. I was using two objects: one declared in the start of the function, and the second one inside the _if_. The second one had a really strange behavior and I am not sure, but the data wasn't being compressed into it. So I moved his declaration near the second one and now everything works. I don't understand, but at least I solved it. Thanks.